# LISP - write a list to file

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I need to write a numeric list to a file and put a `return` at the end of the line.

I have tried with this code but work only for the first element of the list.

```
(defun write-segment (filename segment)
  (cond ((null segment)
         (with-open-file (out filename 
                              :direction :output 
                              :if-exists :append 
                              :if-does-not-exist :create)
           (format out "~%")))
        (T (with-open-file (out filename 
                                :direction :output 
                                :if-exists :append 
                                :if-does-not-exist :create)
             (format out "~D " (first segment))
             (write-segment filename (cdr segment))))))
```

Some one can help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: Your code is unreadable - please fix indentation.

Comment: You are opening the file for every list element. This is monstrously inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description and the code, I am not 100% sure if the following fits what you are after, but I will try anyway. The code in this snippet walks a list of numerical values and writes them to an output file:

```
(defun write-numeric-list(filename l)
  (with-open-file (out filename :direction :output :if-exists :append :if-does-not-exist :create)
    (dolist (segment l)
      (format out "~D " segment))
    (format out "~%")))
```

Sample call:

```
(write-numeric-list "output.txt" (list 1 2 -42))
```

This code opens the output file only once for the entire list, instead of once for each element of the list, as in the original version. You may want to adjust the `:if-exists` and `:if-does-not-exist` options depending on preconditions in your particular situation.

In fact, `format` can walk a list just by its own, using slightly advanced format control strings. Those control strings aren't everybody's cup of tea, but for reference, here is a version of the code using them:

```
(defun write-numeric-list(filename l)
  (with-open-file (out filename :direction :output :if-exists :append :if-does-not-exist :create)
    (format out "~{~D ~}~%" l)))
```

Comment: For added hack value, the format control can be `"~{~D~^ ~}~%"`

Answer (score 2):

What about of appending % to the stream like this:

```
(with-open-file (str "filename.txt"
                     :direction :output
                     :if-exists :supersede
                     :if-does-not-exist :create)
  (format str "~A~%" '(1 2 3 4 5)))
```

In your case I will do something like go througth the list and write to the stream, some thing like this, be carefull with the extra return, also you can add a control before opening the file if yuo do not want to make anything if the list is empty.

```
(defun write-non-empty-list-to-a-file (file-name lst)
  "writes a non empty list to a file if the list is empty creates the file with a return"
  (with-open-file (str file-name
                     :direction :output
                     :if-exists :supersede
                     :if-does-not-exist :create)
    (dolist (e lst)
      (format str "~A~%" e))
    (format str "~%")));this if you want an extra return
```